# How to get the rediected url in the process_request() of scrapy RedirectMiddleware?

Tags: scrapy

For example:
the url is http://www.wandoujia.com/search?key=saber
It will be redirected to the new url http://www.wandoujia.com/search/3161097853842468421.
I want to get the new url in the process_request() of scrapy RedirectMiddleware?

Following is my code:

```
class RedirectMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        new_url = request.url
        logging.debug('new_url = ' + new_url)
        logging.debug('****************************')
        patterns = spider.request_pattern
        logging.debug(patterns)
        for pattern in patterns:
            obj = re.match(pattern, new_url)
            if obj: 
                return Request(new_url)
```

ps:the `request.url` is the old url. I want to get the new url correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry for that the format

Comment: Try printing `request.meta['redirect_urls']` and `request._url` in `process_requests` method, I think you will get some help

Comment: Are you sure？process_requests(),not process_request()?

Comment: process_request() ... sorry it was typo

Comment: I have tried request.meta['redirect_urls'],but error

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the default middleware with something like this (the method you're looking for is the `process_response` because the response "contains the redirection")

```
class CustomRedirectMiddleware(RedirectMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        redirected = super(CustomRedirectMiddleware, self).process_response(
            request, response, spider)
        if isinstance(redirected, request.__class__):
            print("Original url: <{}>".format(request.url))
            print("Redirected url: <{}>".format(redirected.url))
            return redirected
        return response
```

Comment: So,I have another problem. The response in this function is the all content of the url,or just some infomation about the url? You know,if the url is invalid for me,it's too wasteful to crawl the all content of the url.

Comment: I don't follow was the question answered? The only way to know if you're being re-directed is to inspect the response, you could probably do a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` and inspect the response.

Comment: try to get it from response.headers['Location']

Comment: also i'd just avoid splash. i'm currently having this problem. always bugs or site detects splash since its old webkit. who wants to mix lua and python anyways.